# How to read a complex attribute using JSON spirit?

Tags: c++

I have a complex `JSON` attribute with the format as below; I have a main part `"address"` and its sub attribute as present in the format. I'm having a problem using `JSON` spirit in reading the sub attribute by specifying the read query as `address.street_number`. Does anyone have any idea about how to solve this?

```
{
  "address" :
  {
    "street_number" : 5,
    "town" : "xxx",
    "country" : "yyy"
  }
}
```

Comment: I've never worked with JSON spirit, but from my experience, in this cases I usually iterate all over the JSON adding the parameters into a map

Comment: More specifically to a map of maps, map<string, map<string, string>>